# Capturing group with Django 2.0

Tags: django, django-2.0, capturing-group

I am following an older tutorial on creating Django apps. In the section on modifying page URLs the tutorial uses a Regular Expression with a capturing group to pass the parameter in the URL to views.

I am using Django 2.0, so I am using `path` rather than `url`, and I am wondering what the correct substitution for the regular expression is. I have gotten around it for now by using `re_path`, but I'd like to know how it should actually be done in Django 2.0.

The old code is:

```
url(r'([^/]*)', views.index, name='index'),
```

I have made numerous attempts to adapt this to path, including (`pagename` is the parameter in the `index` function):

```
path('/<pagename>', views.index, name='index'),
path('/<str:pagename>', views.index, name='index'),
path('/<str:pagename>/', views.index, name='index'),
```

etc. None of the permutations I could come up with worked and I got a 404 Error every time.

Comment: What is the slash in the front doing here? This is definitely *not* in your `url(..)` regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first take a look at the `url(..)`:

```
url(r'([^/]*)', views.index, name='index'),
```

This means that you accept every path with zero or more characters that are *not* slashes (that is what the `[^/]` means, it means a character group that contains *all* but the slash character, and the *Kleene star* `*` means zero or more repititons).

Now typically in Django one adds a slash at the end, but the path should *not* begin with a slash. So a `path(..)` that should work is:

```
path('<str:pagename>/', views.index, name='index'),
```

Since `str` does not accept a slash as well, the two are now equivalent, except for the fact that `str` should contain at least *one* character. We can for example use two `path(..)`s to include the empty string as well:

```
path('', views.index, name='index', kwargs={'pagename': ''}),
path('<str:pagename>/', views.index, name='index'),
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Willem.  I appreciate your explanation and your answer worked.